# ipython %debug command returning "No traceback has been produced, nothing to debug." after exception

Tags: ipython

Recently, the ipython %debug command stopped working on a jupyterhub server that I manage. After an error, instead of launching the debugger at the line where the exception occurred, it instead returns `No traceback has been produced, nothing to debug.`

I'm guessing there's a dependency that got updated somewhere and is causing the issue, but after variously updating or rolling back my versions of `ipython`, `ipdb`, and a variety of the packages they depend upon, I still haven't found the problem, and I don't have a whole lot of intuition as to other packages that could be relevant here. What are the other libraries that would be relevant to how the ipython `%debug` command determines whether there's a traceback?

```py
In [1]: def raise_error():
   ...:     raise Exception("This is an exception.")
   ...: 

In [2]: raise_error()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 raise_error()

Cell In[1], line 2, in raise_error()
      1 def raise_error():
----> 2     raise Exception("This is an exception.")

Exception: This is an exception.

In [3]: %debug
2023-07-21T23:13:05     ERROR    No traceback has been produced, nothing to debug.
```

Partial list of packages:

```
brotlipy @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotlipy_1666764671472/work
certipy==0.1.3
ipykernel==6.24.0
ipyleaflet==0.17.2
ipympl==0.9.3
ipython==7.34.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.7.1
ipdb==0.13.13
backcall @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/backcall_1592338393461/work
decorator @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/decorator_1641555617451/work
jedi==0.17.2
parso==0.7.1
matplotlib-inline @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/matplotlib-inline_1660814786464/work
traitlets @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/traitlets_1675110562325/work
pexpect @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pexpect_1667297516076/work
ptyprocess @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/ptyprocess_1609419310487/work/dist/ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pickleshare @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pickleshare_1602536217715/work
prompt-toolkit @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/prompt-toolkit_1677600924538/work
wcwidth @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/wcwidth_1673864653149/work
Pygments @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pygments_1672682006896/work
traitlets @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/traitlets_1675110562325/work
```

Comment: I have this same issue, without JupyterLab. But it's on a recent conda environment installation of Python 3.11.4.

Comment: I haven't found the root cause yet myself, but realized that if I manually set `sys.last_traceback` to some arbitrary value, (e.g., `sys.last_traceback = 1`), the ipython debugger logic will not skip, and then `%debug` will launch a debugger at the location of the last exception as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. On my system, the PYTHONBREAKPOINT environment variable was set erroneously to "ipdb" instead of "ipdb.set_trace". Because "ipdb" was not valid code for PYTHONBREAKPOINT, that seemed to interfere with setting the sys.last_traceback flag when I ran %debug. Fixing PYTHONBREAKPOINT removed the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and glad you figured it out on your end. This does not appear to be relevant in my case, sadly.